# Eclipse Java EE - Galileo - Unable to view plugins

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-3.5

I am new to Eclipse so I am having a hard time troubleshooting this problem. I have a new installation of Eclipse Java EE - Galileo on Windows, and I am unable to see any changes made in the IDE after installing plugins. I have verified that the plugins are installed via installation details, but see no changes made.

For example, after installing the maven integration plugin m2eclipse I go to File->New->Project ... and I have no option for maven. After installing the QuickRex plugin I have no view for it etc.

I have tried re-installing the plugins, re-installing Eclipse, and starting Eclipse with the -clean option, but nothing has resolved the issue.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. This is just a wild guess but could you start over with a fresh install and make sure that you uncheck the option **Contact all update sites during install to find required software** as shown below:

[alt text http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/8039/screenshot003ao.png](http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/8039/screenshot003ao.png)

I faced a similar problem (on another platform than yours), some updates were "disabling" all my plugins. Not checking this option allowed me to work around this issue.

**Follow-up:** You'll need to install that Zest stuff manually from the GEF update site:

[alt text http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/8003/screenshot003rl.png](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/8003/screenshot003rl.png)

Comment: That is correct. The plugin shows up as being installed in the installation details, but makes no changes in the IDE (menus, buttons, etc.) The OS is Windows Vista, and I installed the latest version of m2eclipse from the update site at http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e. 

I just used the Maven plugin as an example, but no other plugin shows up either. Even after reinstalling Eclipse. 

Thanks

Comment: Getting an install error when trying that: 

Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Editors) 0.10.0.20100209-0800 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor 0.10.0.20100209-0800) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.zest.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: @Dis Ah yes, indeed, forgot about that. I've updated my answer with instructions.

Comment: OK when I open Help->About Eclipse the m2e icon is not there. When I press installation details it shows the zest toolkit, and Maven Integration. But there is still nothing showing up in the menus.

Comment: @Dis Sorry, running out of ideas then.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I will figure it out eventually :)

Comment: I followed Pascal's instructions a second time, and this time it worked. Issues resolved! Thanks so much.

Comment: @Dis Glad it's solved (I feel less alone now). For the record, this problem and the workaround are discussed in http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg29591.html. Couldn't find an existing ticket in their bugzilla though.